# Which place for Commandline on startup

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I'm using arch linux and my questions is where is the best place to run a commandline programm on the startup.

I want to do some custom stuff on boottime. Like I want to deactivate my graphic card on the startup. I load the module and now I want to run the bash-line to deactivate this.

Where I can do this?

Comment: I know it's a lot of reading to do, but I think for many that is part of becoming an Arch user. I recommend you have a look at [this wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting) about autostarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two main options for you:

1. Write your own script into /etc/init.d
2. Edit the @reboot entry at [Cron.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)